# subquery inside case statement suggestion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query, however I want the sub-query inside the case statement. I have tried different things but no joy. Please can someone suggest

```
select a.PARAMID, a.PERSONOPTID, a.paramdate,(case 
when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>='0301' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='0620') then 'spring' --else 'Summer' 
when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>='0621' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='0920') then 'Summer' -- else 'Autumn' 
when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>='0921' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='1130') then 'Autumn'  else 'winter'
--when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>'1201' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='0228') then 'winter'end 
end)  from personoptions a, personopt po, person 
WHERE a.PARAMID=190 and 
a.PERSONOPTID in (select a.PERSONOPTID from personoptions a
where  a.paramid=185 and 
trunc(a.PARAMDATE) between trunc(sysdate-372)and trunc(sysdate-365)) and 
a.PERSONOPTID = po.PERSONOPTID
AND po.PERSONID = person.personid
AND po.PERSONID  in ( 12345)
```

What I have tried,

```
select (case when exists (select personid from ( select person.personid from personoptions a, personopt po, person
WHERE a.PARAMID=190 and 
a.PERSONOPTID in (select a.PERSONOPTID from personoptions a
where  a.paramid=185 and 
trunc(a.PARAMDATE) between trunc(sysdate-372)and trunc(sysdate-365)) and 
a.PERSONOPTID = po.PERSONOPTID
AND po.PERSONID = person.personid
AND po.PERSONID  in ( 1481198891002120249232017090384761))) then  
(case when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>='0301' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='0620') then 'spring' --else 'Summer' 
when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>='0621' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='0920') then 'Summer' -- else 'Autumn' 
when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>='0921' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='1130') then 'Autumn'  else 'winter'
--when (to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')>'1201' and to_char(a.paramdate,'mmdd')<='0228') then 'winter'end 
end)end) from person
```

Error: Ora-00904:a.paramdate invalid identifier

Comment: Question is not clear. Where you want to put it incase ? In your posted code its working as a filter condition. Post what you tried

Comment: Added the code I tried

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question. Only plain SQL.

Comment: You are trying to access `a.paramdate` from a place where it is not in scope.

Comment: If you formatted your code you would see that the final nested `case` is trying to refer to `a.paramdate` from a table called `person`. I'm guessing that should be `p.paramdate` from `person p`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not have two tables with the same alias (two tables with the alias 'a') because the database might sometimes not understand you and return some wierd results
2. Table used in subquery is only accessible in () that it is used in. You were trying to use table outside of the scope in the case statements at the end of your query.